# Resample a Python Series or Dataframe at Dates Given

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas dataframe or series, I would like to resample it at specific points in time.
This might mean dropping values or adding new values by forward filling previous ones.

### Example

Given the Series `X` defined by

```
import pandas
rng_X = pandas.to_datetime(
['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-02-01'])
X = pandas.Series([0, 2, 4, 6, 8], rng_X)

X
2021-01-01    0
2021-01-02    2
2021-01-07    4
2021-01-08    6
2021-02-01    8
```

Resample `X` at dates

```
rng_Y = pandas.to_datetime(
['2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10'])
```

The expected output is

```
2021-01-02    2
2021-01-03    2
2021-01-07    4
2021-01-08    6
2021-01-09    6
2021-01-10    6
```

- `2021-01-01` is dropped from the output since it isn't in `rng_y`.
- `2021-01-03` is added to the output with its value copied forward from `2021-01-02` since it does not exist in `X`
- `2021-01-09` and `2021-01-10` are also added to the output with values copied from `2021-01-08`
- `2021-02-01` is dropped from the output since it does not exist in `rng_Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html#pandas-series-reindex) with method set to 'ffill':

```
X = X.reindex(rng_Y, method='ffill')
```

`X`:

```
2021-01-02    2
2021-01-03    2
2021-01-07    4
2021-01-08    6
2021-01-09    6
2021-01-10    6
dtype: int32
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd

rng_X = pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08',
                        '2021-02-01'])

rng_Y = pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08',
                        '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10'])

X = pd.Series([0, 2, 4, 6, 8], rng_X)

X = X.reindex(rng_Y, method='ffill')
print(X)
```

---

If `X` was a DataFrame (`df`) instead of a Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0, 2, 4, 6, 8], index=rng_X, columns=['X'])
df = df.reindex(rng_Y, method='ffill')
```

`df`:

```
            X
2021-01-02  2
2021-01-03  2
2021-01-07  4
2021-01-08  6
2021-01-09  6
2021-01-10  6
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it should be simple but I just couldn't find the solution since I was using `resample` in the search query rather than `reindex`.